# проблемы с code blocks, не работаeт пункт properties

Tags: c++, codeblocks

Создал проект в code blocks-е, открыл файл main(), хочу залезть в project-->properties, но не выходит, практически все поля данного пункта не активны. Что делать, подскажите пожалуйста?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: видимо нужно открывать проект, а не просто один файл

Comment: точно, что-то я затормозил, работает, спасибо большое, добрый человек